# How to Get Dropdown SelectedValue included in the generated IdToken

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have country dropdown in the SignUp Policy which is defined like

```
<ClaimType Id="extension_CountryCode">
    <DisplayName>Country</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>Country</UserHelpText>
    <UserInputType>DropdownSingleSelect</UserInputType>
    <Restriction>
      <Enumeration Text="Algeria" Value="213" SelectByDefault="false" />
      <Enumeration Text="Andorra" Value="376" SelectByDefault="false" />
</Restriction>
</ClaimType>
```

I have added this ClaimId like other claims in all the necessary places, but it is throwing this error on signup

"#error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C90161: A self-asserted send response has failed with reason 'Internal Server Error'."

How can I get the Country code claim in the Id Token.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your country codes are all Integer values but this line:

```
<DataType>string</DataType>
```

Implies you are expecting a string. You should just have to change this to

```
<DataType>Int</DataType>
```

And make the extension_CountryCode is also set to Int.

*EDIT* - Hmm Forgot extensions can't be Int so you may be out of luck unless the conversion from int to string works ok with extensions ......

Comment: Note: An extension property can now be of type `String`, `Int` or  `Boolean` when it is created through the Azure AD B2C portal.